# Send email in php after load page

Tags: php

I want send e-mail form website to me after load page.
I have this code

```
<?php 
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "title";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: email@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: email@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Works correctly, but how to get the value of these paragraphs in PHP

```
<p id="nameInfo"></p>
<p id="lastNameInfo"></p>
<p id="streetInfo"></p>
```

I want to download the value of these paragraphs and send it in the body of the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating an endpoint you send your data to, with your PHP script. Then from the front end, you'd use JS to capture the data you want, and then use an AJAX request to send it to your endpoint. Then that endpoint would handle accepting your data, and sending an email.

Although, you'd want to make sure you validate / sanitise this data, and decide if you want this public. As each request could potentially send an email without any security / limiting.

Comment: can you show how to do it? Because I tried something before but it did not work

Comment: I can provide help, but not write your code. If you can provide what you tried, that would be super helpful. Learning by practice! :)

Comment: AJAX 
`$(function(){
var data = {
    name: $("#nameInfo").text(),
    lastName: $("#lastNameInfo").text(),
    message: $("#streetInfo").text()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sklep/email.php",
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
});`
PHP
`if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $message = $_POST['streetInfo'];

    mail("myeiam@gmail.com", $name, $message);
}`

Comment: This code worked, but it always popped a 404 error, did not find the php url

Comment: You'd have to check your endpoint exists. A 404 means it wasn't found. Double check the path and such, and if it can accept POST requests

Comment: I will write the ajax javascript code directly in the html code, I will do the same with the php code, what is the download of the url in ajax then?